# Windowsserver is not running in a docker container. Couldn't pull image either

Tags: docker

Tried to run windowsserver in docker container using below dockerfile but not working.
Below is the dockerfile I am using.

```
# Sample Dockerfile

# Indicates that the windowsservercore image will be used as the base image.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Metadata indicating an image maintainer.
LABEL maintainer="jshelton@contoso.com"

# Uses dism.exe to install the IIS role.
RUN dism.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:iis-webserver /NoRestart

# Creates an HTML file and adds content to this file.
RUN echo "Hello World - Dockerfile" > c:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.html

# Sets a command or process that will run each time a container is run from the new image.
CMD [ "cmd" ]
```

I tried this script on docker running on windows and linux and I get the following error.

**Windows:**

```
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                 0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount892080165/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

**Linux:**

```
[+] Building 0.1s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                          docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 681B                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019                                                                                                                0.1s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019:
------
Dockerfile:4
--------------------
   2 |
   3 |     # Indicates that the windowsservercore image will be used as the base image.
   4 | >>> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
   5 |
   6 |     # Metadata indicating an image maintainer.
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019: no match for platform in manifest sha256:4fe58f25a157ea749c7b770acebfdbd70c3cb2088c446943e90fe89ea059558b: not found
```

I tried just pulling the windowsserver docker image, but that didn't work either. Tried on both windows and linux machine, I get below error.

**Docker command:  docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019**

**Error:**

```
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

Windowsserver should run in docker container.

**Note:
Now i can able to create the windowsserver image on windows. After enable the switch to windows container, But i got issue while start the container i got error.**

```
docker: Error response from daemon: hcs::CreateComputeSystem 8863b41bfec989486ba1f1e28fce049cffed38c7ccbbcba29e7a4a3b2914d49d: The request is not supported.
```